# How to extract the values of 2 nested dictionary and summing their respective values together without using any import functions?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary that looks something like that

```
{A:{'score': 0, 'throw1': [3, 2, 5, 6], 'throw2': [1, 5, 5, 1]},
 'B': {'score': 0, 'throw1': [2, 2, 3, 6], 'throw2': [6, 4, 2, 2]}}
```

A and B are players in this game and the throw1 and throw2 are their dice rolls. Each player has 4 attempts.

My question is how do i extract both throw1 and throw2 from the dictionary and sum their respective attempts together for each player. For instance, Player A threw 3 and 1 for their first attempt on both throws. I want the answer to be 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) that returns an iterator of tuples

```
data = {'A': {'score': 0, 'throw1': [3, 2, 5, 6], 'throw2': [1, 5, 5, 1]},
        'B': {'score': 0, 'throw1': [2, 2, 3, 6], 'throw2': [6, 4, 2, 2]}}

player_A_1_results = data['A']['throw1']
player_A_2_results = data['A']['throw2']

for f, s in zip(player_A_1_results, player_A_2_results):
    print(f + s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate each players throw summary like below

```py
data = {'A': {'score': 0, 'throw1': [3, 2, 5, 6], 'throw2': [1, 5, 5, 1]},
        'B': {'score': 0, 'throw1': [2, 2, 3, 6], 'throw2': [6, 4, 2, 2]}}


for player, info in data.items():
    print("Throw summary of player "+player)

    for t1, t2 in zip(info["throw1"], info["throw2"]):
        print(t1+t2)
```